# jQuery Lightbox animate Problem in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm using this code to create an overlay and a overlaid box:

```
// GENERAL OVERLAY BOX
var isOpen = false; // STATUS OF OVERLAY BOX
function showOverlayBox() { // DISPLAY BOX
    if( isOpen == false ) return; // DO NOTHING IF NOT SET TO OPEN
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.overlayBox').css({ // OVERLAY BOX POSITION
        display:'block',
        left:( $(window).width() - $('.overlayBox').width() )/2,
        top:( $(window).height() - $('.overlayBox').height() )/2 -20,
        position:'absolute'
    });
    $('.bgCover').css({ // DARK BG
        display:'block',
        width: $(window).width(),
        height:$(window).height()
    });
}
function doOverlayOpen() { // OPEN
    isOpen = true; // SET STATUS TO OPEN
    showOverlayBox();
    $('.bgCover').css({opacity:0}).animate( {opacity:0.8, backgroundColor:'#000'} );
    return false;
    }
function doOverlayClose() { // CLOSE OVERLAY
    isOpen = false; //SET STATUS TO CLOSED
        $('.overlayBox').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('.bgCover').animate( {opacity:0}, null, null, function() { $(this).hide(); } ); WON'T WORK IN IE7
        $('.bgCover').hide();
        }
$(window).bind('resize',showOverlayBox);// IF WINDOW IS RESIZED, REPOSITION OVERLAY
$('.launchLink').click( doOverlayOpen ); // OPEN OVERLAY WHEN a.launchLink CLICKED
$('a.closeLink').click( doOverlayClose ); // CLOSE OVERLAY WHEN a.closeLink CLICKED
```

In IE7, I have no problems opening and closing the content box -- the problem is with the .bgCover . It will animate in, but will not animate out using `$('.bgCover').animate( {opacity:0}, null, null, function() { $(this).hide(); } );` It will hide with: `$('.bgCover').hide();`, but then won't re-appear if the box overlay is brought up again. (No problems in other browsers)

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: If `.hide()` will work--try changing the animate in to `.show()` to see if it'll work that way. Just a thought.

Comment: No luck -- since it works fine in other browsers, I think it has to be sort of IE quirk

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.bgCover').remove();
```

I found that using hide() can be troublesome with overlays.